# How to query data via a .netcore app from Google Analytics V4

Tags: .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

I found a lot of examples online regarding the topic, but apparently Google have switched to a new way of presenting the data in Google Analytics.

In their V4 (for which I guess there is a nuget package, since the letter "V" and the number "4" appear in the name of the dll - Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4) version there are no Views. You go to Admin -> Account -> Property and that's it - no views.

As far as I read the ViewId is mandatory for the request when you query GA.

I can only assume that there is a new way of doing it now.

I have the setup: the api is enabled in the project I created in the Google Console, a service account is created, the authentication is done via json file, the user associated with that service account is added as an admin in Account Access Management in GA.

But how to query the reporting api from .netcore? Is there another package with newer libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal analytics and Google Analytics GA4 are two completely different systems and they can not be intermixed.

Universal analytics has view ids,  GA4 has measurement ids.

The APIs used to access these different systems are also different so there for they also have their own nuget packages.

[Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4/) is used for the Google analytics reporting api, and all of the other apis which gives you access to the data behind `Universal analytics accounts`. It cant give you access to `GA4` the data isnt the same.

## How to access GA4

To access GA4 accounts you need to go though the Google analytics data api and the Google analytics admin api.

- [Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta/1.0.0-beta08)  (Reports)
- [Google analytics admin alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.GoogleAnalyticsAdmin.v1alpha/) (Managment)

At the time of writing both of these apis are in fact still in beta and alpha.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS  C:\tmp\ServiceAccountCred.json
var client = await BetaAnalyticsDataClient.CreateAsync(CancellationToken.None);
var request = new RunReportRequest
{
    Property = "properties/" + PropertyId,
    Dimensions = {new Dimension {Name = "date"},},
    Metrics = {new Metric {Name = "totalUsers"},new Metric {Name = "newUsers"}},
    DateRanges = {new DateRange {StartDate = "2021-04-01", EndDate = "today"},},
};
var response = await client.RunReportAsync(request);
foreach (var row in response.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{row.DimensionValues[0].Value}, {row.MetricValues[0].Value}, {row.MetricValues[1].Value}");
}
```

Code shamelessly ripped from my tutorial [Guide to Google analytics Data Api Beta with C#](https://www.daimto.com/export-data-from-google-analytics-4-with-c/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I will read your tutorial!
The only thing I am afraid of is the word "beta" in the nuget packages. But it is as good as it gets, I suppose, after all they are NOW developing it and it is extremely new.
Cheers!

Comment: @BorislavNanovski that tutorial was written a year ago when the api first came out.  Please let me know if you have any issues and i will update it.

Comment: Will do! Also... if not the .netcore api, is there a REST api that one can use directly making http requests?

Comment: You can access them though the rest api [runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)  The issue you will have is the authorization part.  Service account authorization isnt something you want to code from scratch.  it uses JWT tokens that need to be configured properly in order to work.   Its easer to let the library do it for you.  Most of .net core is EOL now you should consider upgrading .net 6

Comment: Upgrade to what?

Comment: Are you sure it wont work with .Net core?  it looks like its still targeting [.net standard](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta/Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.csproj#L5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244602/discussion-between-borislav-nanovski-and-daimto).

Comment: For Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta: do you guys know of an alternative to using a json file to create the client? We use Azure and are used to storing APIKeys in App Config for integrating with 3rd party apis. How might we have the credentials there instead of relying on pointing to a json file on a file system?

Comment: @MattoMK you should be able to load them directly using azure secrets.